# Git merge is going nuts when merging one branch into another

Tags: git, merge, branching-and-merging

I have a master branch which we use for the third party vendor's baseline, and another branch for our institution's custom modifications. We've been using this for awhile, and there are quite a few commits in both. Usually when it's time to update the baseline, things go smoothly, just one or two conflicts in a 40,000 Pro*C file, and they're small and easy to resolve manuallly.

The latest baseline was made available last week, and I've jut gotten around to trying it. I committed it into the master branch, and when I do a merge to the custom branch it says there's a conflict. When I open the file and do a search, Sublime is telling me that there are 990 matches for "<<<<<<< HEAD".

There should be very few changes with the new baseline, and most of them should be minor and easy to resolve algorithmicly. At the very top of the file, I get this:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
#define TM_ON_STARTUP tmInitGlobS_szrtrtc
=======
#define TM_ON_STARTUP tmInitGlobS_szrtrtc
>>>>>>> master
```

Sublime shows whitespace too, and they appear identical. Many are like this. A few (hard to tell, maybe a third of them) however, do have minor whitespace changes:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
/*    Solution: Heading is changed to 'Current Program'.                    */
=======
/*    Solution: Heading is changed to 'Current Program'.                    */  
>>>>>>> master
```

In this one, master has a tab at the end of the comment. So I can see that it found a difference, but I still can't understand why it failed to simply apply the change (I don't care if there's a tab there or not).

Why is it doing this? At first, I thought there might be a line-endings mismatch between the two branches that I might have introduced with the latest commit. That doesn't seem to be the case.

This happens whether I use Sourcetree, or switch back to msysgit and use it (same number of conflict hunks).

Can anyone lend any insight on what I might have screwed up for it to start doing this? What should I check when debugging the behavior? Should I just man up and resolve these manually (not all are one-line conflicts) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ignore whitespace differences with `git merge master --strategy=recursive -Xignore-all-space`

Comment: That doesn't seem to be an option. https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html

Comment: Looks like the actual command should be git merge master --strategy=recursive -Xignore-all-space (a few others, including only space at eol). Thanks for the tip... now it's down to a manageable 15 conflicts.

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect the more detailed syntax :;):